Flash Sparkfun board with Nordic SDK tools in Visual Studio
I have a SparkFun Pro nRF52840 Mini that I am trying to flash with a simple Hello World program. I am trying to use the Nordic SDK with Visual Studio for this. I have the SDK setup, created the custom board configuration for the mini, and the Hello World application built correctly. However I cannot see the board on Connected Devices after plugging it into my PC.
I saw somewhere on the Nordic forum something about the SDK only registering Nordic development kits but I haven't gotten any responses yet. If this is true how would I go about using the SDK to flash this board? Do you have to use a Nordic development kit that can be seen by the SDK to then flash it?
I am planning to eventually spin this off into a custom PCB and I would love to keep the pipeline the same as with this Sparkfun dev board.
Also I apologize if I am missing anything obvious I am a software guy just learning more of the hardware stuff.
Thanks!

Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?  Not the same thing (and not "Studios").  The Nordic SDK is certainly specific to Nordic chips; I would be amazed if they detected Thier specific boards.

This https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/nrf52840-advanced-development-with-the-nrf5-sdk has a section on adding DFU-programming targets in VSCode for this board.  You probably need to do that (and read the whole tutorial in any case).
